# Html String to Pdf conversion in Java, Styling is not working as expected

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am trying to convert HTML string to PDF in java using itext library. Conversion of html to pdf is fine but styling is not working as expected. [Here is the html page](https://codepen.io/im5an/pen/vYxqepe) which I want to convert to PDF. Can anyone please help me to convert this Html string to PDF with proper styling as shown in [link](https://codepen.io/im5an/pen/vYxqepe). Here is the code which I tried in Java

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream("index.html"), 
new FileOutputStream("index-to-pdf.pdf"));
```

Depedency which I used are

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.9</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help me to create a PDF with styling from html string using non paid library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the whole code, it is unable to understand your problem. but I used your HTML reference and it's working perfectly fine for generating HTML to pdf using the above code and library.

here is a [link](https://github.com/negirox/javaHTMLtoPDF/tree/master) to my repository with your HTML you can check.

I am adding a sample of your pdf after generating it with CSS[image].

Comment: The generated PDF is styling is different as shown in this page [link](https://codepen.io/im5an/pen/vYxqepe)

Comment: modify your html. you will get your shot

Comment: @HaiderAli see my index.html I have modified CSS for Zone name you can modify similar.